# Elasticsearch query without stop words in aggregation result

Tags: elasticsearch

In my index-template, I have defined a custom analyzer, where a stop words filter is included. See following snippet:

```
  "settings": {
     "index.analysis.filter.german_stemmer.type": "stemmer",
     "index.analysis.filter.german_stop.type": "stop",
     "index.analysis.filter.german_stemmer.language": "light_german",
     "index.analysis.filter.german_keywords.keywords.0": "",
     "index.analysis.filter.german_stop.stopwords": "_german_",
     "index.analysis.filter.german_keywords.type": "keyword_marker",
     "index.analysis.analyzer.unigram.filter.0": "lowercase",
     "index.analysis.analyzer.unigram.filter.1": "german_stop",
     "index.analysis.analyzer.unigram.filter.2": "german_keywords",
     "index.analysis.analyzer.unigram.filter.3": "german_normalization",
     "index.analysis.analyzer.unigram.filter.4": "german_stemmer",
     "index.analysis.analyzer.unigram.tokenizer": "standard",
  }
```

I have also defined a mapping for unigram on the `textBody`-field. At next I try to get the most frequent words, by looking at the top-100 document counts:

```
  "aggs":{
    "wordcounts":{
      "terms":{
        "field" : "textBody",
        "size" : 100
      }
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately in this approach, there are also stop words included in the results. This stop words have a high document count, but zero word frequency (follow up query via `script field tf()`). Is there a way to remove the stop words from my aggregation result?

P.S.: The significant terms query also gives me stop words in my result set.

Examples for german stop words: "viel", "muss", "soll", "war", "weg", "den", ...

I am using elasticsearch-groovy:1.7.0, which is build on top of:

- elasticsearch:1.7.0
- lucene-core:4.10.4

**update:**

I figured out, that there are some word forms which are reduced to the words mentioned above. For example "muss" is in the text in the following word forms: "muss", "muesse", "muessen", "muß", "muße", "müsse" and "müsser". These words all get reduced to the stemmed word "muss". If I query for the word "muss", then I get zero results, because it gets filtered by the stop words filter.

In some queries (e.g. must_not filter) it is even possible to query "muss" and as a result I get the aggregated count of all other word forms then "muss".

Comment: Which elasticsearch and lucene version are you running? I suspect that older lucene versions didn't include all your stopwords

Comment: elasticsearch 1.7.0, lucene 4.10.4

Answer (score 0):

Lucene versions prior to 5.0 appear to use an hard coded list of stopwords. [(view source code)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.10.4/org/apache/lucene/analysis/de/GermanAnalyzer.java?av=f). This does not include "viel", "muss", "soll", "weg", "den". It does include "war".

Hovever, you can specify a `stopwords_path` to a file containing all the stopwords that you need to have (See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-stopwords.html).

From version 5.0 the stopwords are always read from file, but I could not find the text of the default file. I found some files and they where richer than the hard coded list of version 4.10.4, but I don't know which one is used by default ([here is one](https://github.com/buric/GermanStopWords/blob/master/de_DE_stop.txt))

Comment: if i apply the `stopwords_path` with your file, do i get 100 results in my aggregation query without stopwords?

Comment: @boraas the file is not mine; don't do anything in production, try in dev environment